# Outputting string depending on color detected in video feed

Tags: opencv, c++-cli, emgucv

so what I'm trying to do is output a certain string depending on the color I see in the video feed. For right now, what I've done is threshold the feed so that everything above a certain brightness shows up as Red. Now I want to have something that says if there's any red in the feed, then I output a "1" to a text box on my user interface that's showing the feed. If there is no red, then I output a "0" to the text box. I'm using Emgu CV Managed C++ with VS2010, can anyone help me? Thank you.

This is the code I have so far that isn't working correctly, it's giving me a compiler error.

```
cvConvertScaleAbs(frameFromCamera->Ptr.ToPointer(),frameDisplay->Ptr.ToPointer(),double(1)/16,0);
    cvCvtColor(frameDisplay->Ptr.ToPointer(),frameColorDisplay->Ptr.ToPointer(),CV_GRAY2BGR);
    cvThreshold(frameDisplay->Ptr.ToPointer(),maskSaturated->Ptr.ToPointer(),200,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cvNot(maskSaturated->Ptr.ToPointer(),mask1->Ptr.ToPointer());
    cv::Scalar red(0,0,255);
    cvSet(frameColorDisplay->Ptr.ToPointer(),red,maskSaturated->Ptr.ToPointer());

    highColor = gcnew Emgu::CV::Image<Bgr,UInt16>(0, 0, 255);
    lowColor = gcnew Emgu::CV::Image<Bgr,UInt16>(0, 0, 200);

    if(maskSaturated->InRange(lowColor, highColor) == 255){
        tbMorse->Text ="1";
    }
    else{
        tbMorse->Text = "0";
    }
    imageMain->Image=frameColorDisplay;
```

and i have highColor and lowColor initialized in my header as such

```
Emgu::CV::Image<Bgr,UInt16> ^lowColor;
    Emgu::CV::Image<Bgr,UInt16> ^highColor;
```

and the error it's giving me is

```
 BAOTFISInterface.cpp(1010): error C2664: 'Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth>::Image(int,int,Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'int' to 'Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr'
      with
      [
          TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr,
          TDepth=unsigned short
      ]
      No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion,         or the operator cannot be called
 BAOTFISInterface.cpp(1011): error C2664: 'Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth>::Image(int,int,Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'int' to 'Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr'
      with
      [
          TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr,
          TDepth=unsigned short
      ]
      No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
 BAOTFISInterface.cpp(1013): error C2664: 'Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth> ^Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth>::InRange(Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth> ^,Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth> ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth> ^' to 'Emgu::CV::Image<TColor,TDepth> ^'
      with
      [
          TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Gray,
          TDepth=unsigned char
      ]
      and
      [
          TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Bgr,
          TDepth=unsigned short
      ]
      and
      [
          TColor=Emgu::CV::Structure::Gray,
          TDepth=unsigned char
      ]
      No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
      Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: The problem is that you're not using C++, you're using C++/CLI which is a very similar language, but is a separate language. For example, it's a managed language, which have a special kind of pointers that are garbage-collected. Those are the ones which uses `^` instead of `*` of normal C++. The managed pointers of C++/CLI are not compatible with ordinary unmanaged pointers, which is what your error is about. The function expects a managed pointer and you gave it an unmanaged one.

Comment: Oh that's kind of confusing. So how would I fix it? How would i make that into a managed pointer? Do i have to declare it as a managed pointer? Thanks for your prompt response! @JoachimPileborg

Comment: If you use a managed library (which is what Emgu CV is) then you need to use the managed features of C++/CLI. So yes, you should use managed pointers, allocated like `SomeType^ var = gcnew SomeType;`

Comment: I'm sorry that's such a jumbled mess, I'm not sure how to put code into comments :(

Comment: You don't. Put code into comments I mean. :) Update your question instead, or post a new question.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll update my question then